# How to verify the rank of the operator on a finite dimensional vector space V?

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, matrix-rank, jordan-normal-form

let $U$ be any linear operator on a finite dimensional vector space.
If rank $U^m = U^{m+1},$ for some positive integer m. 
Then Rank $U^m =$ Rank $U^k,$ for k $\geq$ m.

For Diagnol matrices, the result is obvious.

Is that neccessary that the characteristic polynomial of finite dimensional space always splits. If so, the problem reduces to prove for only jordan blocks.

Comment: I think you mean $\operatorname{rank } U^m = \operatorname{rank } U^{m + 1}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Since rank is invariant under similarity, it's enough to prove this for matrices in Jordan Canonical Form.

> **Additional hint** First establish the claim for a Jordan block of arbitrary eigenvalue and size.

Comment: So the characteristic polynomial splits always ?

Comment: Over an algebraically closed field, yes. And we may as well regard all of our matrices as over an algebraically closed field, since matrix rank doesn't change when one extends the base field.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Rank of the Jordan block reduces only when eigen value is zero. In that case rank of the matrix becomes zero after multiplying it n times.

Comment: @RisingStar You're welcome. And yes, the role of Jordan blocks of eigenvalue zero and size $> 1$ is the key idea here.